# Two different queries to different object, same result

Tags: c#, linq, include, instance, unit-of-work

I'm using UoW, so I think the problem is in that the two queries have the same context.

for example if I do:

```
IEnumerable listProjects = ((IQueryableUnitOfWork)UnitOfWork)
.CreateSet<Project>().Include(p=>p.Users).AsEnumerable();
```

and then I do:

```
IEnumerable listProjectsWithoutIncludes = ((IQueryableUnitOfWork)UnitOfWork)
.CreateSet<Project>().AsEnumerable();
```

In the object **listProjectsWithoutIncludes** the users of the project are stored, as if I did the query with includes.

Does someone know how to prevent that? Thanks.

Comment: If it is the same Unit Of Work then this is working as expected. If you want them to be isolated then you would use a different unit of work? The whole concept of UoW is that you are grouping actions together to form a unit of work. If they are separate items that MUST not interact then they are not one part of unit of work?

Comment: Thanks Belogix, i didn't know that Unit Of Work work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from my comment... [Unit Of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) by its very nature groups everything together as a package or transaction. In your example if you wanted to keep the actions isolated and ignorant of each other then you would need two different units of work.

Think of a unit of work as a single transaction so if you had 5 stones and took 2 away then you would have 3 each and every time thereafter during **THAT** transaction. However, if you had a different unit of work it would always see 5 stones (until committed etc) as it is not part of the firsts transaction.

I hope that makes sense? Unit of work = Transaction = Group of work. If the actions don't make sense to go together in that one transaction then create a new unit of work and so on.